# How to make fuzzy search between lists showing matches and not found elements?

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, rapidfuzz

I'm trying to make a fuzzy match for the values in list `to_search`. Search each value in `to_search` within
`choices` list and show the corresponding item from `result` list. Like a MS Excel VLookUp, but with fuzzy search.

This is my current code that almost print the correct output for different values, but for the values of `to_search` that
don't have any similarity within `choices`, I´d like to show in output `Not Found`, but currently I'm getting some other output.

**The search I´m looking for is by prefix**, this is in the same order. For example the value `38050` appears with this match `('358', 72.0, 8)` because 3, 5 and 8 are present in 38050, but for me is not of interest since 3, 5 and 8 are in different order. Would be a match for me if the choice found would be 380XX, that at least has similarity in prefix compared with 38050. I hope you understand my explanation.

```
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz

choices = [
        '237','1721','124622','334','124624','124','1246','1876','358',
        '33751','33679','599','61','230','31','65','1721','1','124623'
    ]

result = [
            'NAD','ATE','STA','SSI','GYP','RIC','EEC','AND','GIU','ANC',
            'PAI','GAR','TAL','ANI','LAN','TRI','GDO','MAR','EDE'
        ]

to_search = ['18763044','187635','23092','3162','38050','33','49185','51078','1246','1721']

for element in to_search:
    match =  process.extractOne(element, choices, scorer=fuzz.WRatio)
    print(element,result[match[2]],'         ## ',match)
```

**Current output**

```
>>>
18763044    AND         ##  ('1876', 90.0, 7)
187635      AND         ##  ('1876', 90.0, 7)
23092       ANI         ##  ('230', 90.0, 13)
3162        LAN         ##  ('31', 90.0, 14)
38050       GIU         ##  ('358', 72.0, 8) // This should be marked as NOT FOUND
33          SSI         ##  ('334', 90.0, 3)
49185       MAR         ##  ('1', 90.0, 17)  // This should be marked as NOT FOUND
51078       MAR         ##  ('1', 90.0, 17)  // This should be marked as NOT FOUND
1246        EEC         ##  ('1246', 100.0, 6)
1721        ATE         ##  ('1721', 100.0, 1)
```

**The output I'm trying to get:**

```
18763044    AND
187635      AND
23092       ANI
3162        LAN
38050       NOT FOUND
33          SSI
49185       NOT FOUND
51078       NOT FOUND
1246        EEC
1721        ATE
```

In table format for easy understanding of inputs and output. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create you own scorer:

```
def my_scorer(query,choice,**kwargs):
    # default score
    score=fuzz.WRatio(query,choice)

    is_prefix=False

    # if choice is a prefix of query
    if choice in query and query.index(choice)==0:
        is_prefix=True

    # if query is a prefix of choice
    if query in choice and choice.index(query)==0:
        is_prefix=True

    if not is_prefix:
        score=-1

    return score
```

And pass it to `process.extractOne` along with `score_cutoff=0` to ignore results with score lower than `0`:

```
match = process.extractOne(element, choices, scorer=my_scorer, score_cutoff=0) 
if match:
  print(element, result[match[2]])
else:
  print(element, 'NOT FOUND')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your solution seems to work with sample. I'll test with actual data that has thousands of values.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a scorer that will take order more into account than `WRatio`. Then set `score_cutoff` to exclude results below a given similarity.

For your example, `fuzz.ratio` with `score_cutoff=60` seems to work. You'll have to test on bigger datasets and try different scorers to know what you need exactly:

```
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz

choices = [
        '237','1721','124622','334','124624','124','1246','1876','358',
        '33751','33679','599','61','230','31','65','1721','1','124623'
    ]

result = [
            'NAD','ATE','STA','SSI','GYP','RIC','EEC','AND','GIU','ANC',
            'PAI','GAR','TAL','ANI','LAN','TRI','GDO','MAR','EDE'
        ]

to_search = ['18763044','187635','23092','3162','38050','33','49185','51078','1246','1721']

for element in to_search:
    match =  process.extractOne(element, choices, scorer=fuzz.ratio, score_cutoff=60)
    if match:
        print(element,result[match[2]],'         ## ',match)
    else:
        print(element,"NOT FOUND")
```

Output:

```
18763044 AND          ##  ('1876', 66.66666666666667, 7)
187635 AND          ##  ('1876', 80.0, 7)
23092 ANI          ##  ('230', 75.0, 13)
3162 LAN          ##  ('31', 66.66666666666667, 14)
38050 NOT FOUND
33 SSI          ##  ('334', 80.0, 3)
49185 NOT FOUND
51078 NOT FOUND
1246 EEC          ##  ('1246', 100.0, 6)
1721 ATE          ##  ('1721', 100.0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your solution seems to work with sample. I'll test with actual data that has thousands of values.